# Exponent rule and square roots?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

For some $x$,

$\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$

However, for $x= -1$.

$\sqrt{(-1)^2} = (-1^2)^{1/2} = (-1)^{2/2} = (-1)^1 = -1$

Isn't this paradoxical?

Comment: $\sqrt{-1^2}\neq\sqrt{(-1)^2}$.

Comment: The trick is that you can't generally say that $(a^p)^q = a^{pq}$ unless $a$ is positive.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar Typo, sorry about that.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar and Eleven-Eleven: $((-1)^2)^{1/2}$ is, by definition, $\sqrt{(-1)^2}$.  However, $(-1^2)^{1/2} \neq (-1)^{2/2}$.  This "rule" does not always hold, so long as you define $x^{1/n}$ to be a function on $x$.

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven that was a typo, just fixed it.  The main point stands.

Comment: Agreed...THe OP's original problem stood as $\sqrt{-1^2}$, which is why I answered it the way I did.  ONce he changed it, I realized it and deleted my post.  I also agree with your comment which gets to the root of the issue.

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven: ah, fair enough, I guess I misunderstood your objection.  Also, "root of the issue" is a very appropriate phrase here.

Answer (score 7):

As I said in the comment, the problem with this series of equalities is that we cannot generally say that $(a^{p})^q = a^{pq}$.  So, in this instance, 
$$
((-1)^{2})^{1/2} \neq (-1)^{2/2}
$$
The equation $(a^{p})^q = a^{pq}$ will hold, however, as long when either $p$ and $q$ are both integers or $a$ is a positive number.

Answer (score 4):

To get to the problem here, we start with $\sqrt{(-1)^2}$.  Please note that, before dealing with the square root, that $(-1)^2\neq -1^2$.  $(-1)^2=(-1)(-1)=1$, while $-1^2=-(1^2)=-1$.

We can rewrite this using rational exponents, so
$$\sqrt{(-1)^2}=((-1)^2)^{1/2}$$
I believe here, though we can just remedy the situation using our order of operations.  Since we do what is in parentheses before handling exponents, we can go on and say that 
$$((-1)^2)^{1/2}=(1)^{1/2}=\sqrt{1}=1$$

We should also take into account the fact, though, that, as Omnomnomnomnom pointed out that we can't generally say using rules of exponents that $(a^m)^n=a^{mn}$ for all $a$.  Since in this problem $a=-1$, we can't use exponential rules either.

Comment: Eventually someone has to answer it though, right?

Comment: @RyanSullivant These questions, some confusion with square roots, never ever end.